# Prevent rubber band scrolling without disabling scrolling on iOS

Tags: ios, scroll, rubber-band

Current solutions I've seen so far to solve the rubber band scrolling problem on iOS devices disables scrolling entirely.

Is there a concise solution to disable the effect without having to use markup?

Comment: Are you talking about html content in a web view or home screen web app? Or a native UIScrollView?

Comment: Home screen web app :)

Comment: @MikeWeller I answered this before you asked your question. Anywho - will delete the answer. OP: in the future you should put info that Mike asked in the original question :)